# Syntax for multiple joins in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

Working on Oracle: I am attempting to do an inner self join, with a where clause, then take that result and do a left outer join on it:

```
(select * from table1 A
inner join
select * from table1 B
on A.id = B.id
where
A.id is not null and B.id is not null) C
left outer join
select * from table2 D
on C.id = D.id
```

Somehow I am syntactically challenged and can't make this work.  Can't seem to find the right syntax anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just the put the where clause at the end. The database will get it right:

```
select * 
from table1 A
inner join table1 B on A.id = B.id
left join table2 D on D.id = A.id
where A.id is not null
```

In this case, we can take advantage of the logical [transitive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) for your id column joins and where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your second join needs to be joined to a query add a **select * from** at the beginning

```
select * from (select * from table1 A
inner join
select * from table1 B
on A.id = B.id
where
A.id is not null and B.id is not null) C
left outer join
select * from table2 D
on C.id = D.id
```